# Cannot obtain DBObject for transient instance, save a valid instance first with grails and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails

Cannot obtain DBObject for transient instance, save a valid instance first.

I am using grails 2.2.1 and mongodb 1.2.0. There is a Domain like below.

```
class Person{
 static mapWith = "mongo"
 static hasMany = [categories:Category , address:Address];

 String firstName;
 String lastName;
 String emailId;
 int age;
 String contactNumber;
 String sex;
 byte [] personImage;
 String identity;
 static constraints = {
    identity nullable: true , inList:["Driving License"] , unique: true;
    emailId email: true , unique: true
    contactNumber unique: true 
 }
}
```

When i am going to save it is giving error.

Comment: show us how you are saving the object, also its values , also post the error message you are getting.

Comment: Looks like you are using an older version of Grails mongodb plugin. Please upgrade the plugin to latest version 3.0.3 and try again.